# Disable darkened / shaded screen on Authentication Required prompt?

Tags: gnome, password, root, authentication

When the "Authentication Required" window appears, everything behind it, and everything on other screens, are darkened. Is it possible to disable this shading effect? [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRFUJ.jpg)

Comment: No, it's not possible.